# I don't have any idea to use STAF/STAX with AutoIt/Sikuli

Tags: autoit, sikuli

I can't find any tutorial linking staf/stax to AutoIt/ Sikuli. I need it for test automation. I hope some of you may refer some links for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a good tutorial for Sikuli at the moment, it would be usefull though. I learned by exporing it myself, and asking questions. Also Sikuli works very well with Java and Python. Especialy python seems to be much used with it.

If you are looking for some Sikuli commands, have a look here: [Link](http://doc.sikuli.org/) 
Especialy below the section `Complete Guide to Sikuli Script`. 
There is a lot of handy code parts to use.

On the top of the page there is a `Hello World` tutorial.